# lightbgm sklearn n_estimators and n_estimators_

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

I set n_estimators to 50 in lightgbm sklearn interface. When fitting stopped, n_estimators_ is 100. Why is this the case?

```
regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators=50)
```

n_estimators (int, optional (default=100)) – Number of boosted trees to fit.

n_estimators_:
True number of boosting iterations performed.

Why is n_estimators_ double that of n_estimators_? Aren't they supposed to be the same?

Comment: I've provided an answer below and I hope it solves your question... but I had to guess at a lot of details. In the future, please provide a minimal, reproducible example ([docs on that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to increase the chance of generating relevant answers and decrease the effort required to provide those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lightgbm==4.3.0` on macOS (Python 3.11.7, `scikit-learn==1.4.1`), I'm not able to reproduce that.

```py
import lightgbm
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators=50)
regressor.fit(X, y)

regressor.n_estimators
# 50

regressor.n_estimators_
# 50
```

I suspect that maybe you called `.fit()` twice, passing the already-fitted model in as `init_model` the second time, which resulted in LightGBM performing an *additional* 50 rounds of boosting.

```py
# fit again
regressor.fit(X, y, init_model=regressor)

regressor.n_estimators
# 50

regressor.n_estimators_
# 100
```

Those properties have slightly different meanings:

- `.n_estimators` = maximum number of boosting rounds to perform next time `fit()` is called
- `.n_estimators_` = total number of trees in the model

Comment: You are right, I did pass the already-fitted model in as init_model. Thanks.